# Resent headers in MIME email

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, mime, email-client, james

I want to know more about the resent headers (resent-from, resent-to, resent-date etc) that get prepended to an email's header.
When do these headers get added? Do they get added by the server or the mail client program?

I need to write a Java program using JavaMail api to forward an email (without changing or parsing through it's original content). I would like the email to be redirected to the destination email address on arriving at the server for a specific recepient.
Any snippet where you have been able to forward / redirect a mime mail using the resent headers will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See section 3.6.6 of [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

You should be able to use JavaMail to add these headers to a message.  If the message was read from a folder on a mail server, you'll need to make a copy of the message first before you can change it.  Use the [MimeMessage copy constructor](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage%28javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage%29).  You can then send it to whatever address you want, ignoring the addresses in the message, by using the [Transport.send method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send%28javax.mail.Message,%20javax.mail.Address%5B%5D%29) that takes an array of addresses.  If you need to preserve the original Message-ID (which may not be appropriate since you're modifying the message), you'll need to subclass MimeMessage and override the updateHeaders method.

Comment: If I add resent headers, and then use the Transport.send function to send the message, what will JavaMail do? Send the email to the 'Resent-To' user from the 'Resent-From' user? Or, will it send it the regular way (i.e. to the 'To' user from the 'From' user). What role do resent headers play? Are they only for information / display purposes, or are they used while delivering the messages?

Comment: If you use the send method that takes a list of addresses, it will send only to those addresses, ignoring any headers in the message.